# How can I reverse the y-axis in a raster plot?

Tags: r, r-raster

I would like to plot a raster with the y-axis increasing from top to bottom, and the raster correspondingly flipped. Is there a way to do this? Specifying `ylim` in decreasing order gives an error.

For example, I would like this plot with the y-axis running from -100 at the top to 100 at the bottom, with the raster also reversed to put green on top and orange on the bottom:

```r
library(raster)
r <- raster(nrows=10, ncols=10)
r <- setValues(r, 1:ncell(r))
plot(r)
```

[image]

```r
# Fails
plot(r, ylim=c(100, -100))
#> Error in .plotraster2(x, col = col, maxpixels = maxpixels, add = add, : invalid ylim
```

<sup>Created on 2020-10-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach shown below appears to work

Example data

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(nrows=10, ncols=10, vals=1:100)
```

Flip the raster vertically, and add the horizontal axis

```
plot(flip(r, "y"), axes=F)
axis(1)
```

Get the labels for the vertical axis, and plot them in reverse order

```
ylabs <- axis(2, labels=FALSE, tick=FALSE)
axis(2, at=ylabs, labels=rev(ylabs))
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to find out what labels the plot would use, rather than hard-coding ylabs?